# How to delete settings in Wordpress on plugin uninstall?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing my first WordPress plugin and register plugin settings on admin_init hook:

```
register_setting( 'option_group', 'option_name', 'sanitize_callback' );
```

It works, great. On deactivating (register_deactivation_hook) I set:

```
unregister_setting( 'option_group', 'option_name' );
```

It also works. BUT how to delete this settings on plugin uninstall? When I put

```
delete_option( 'option_name' );
```

in uninstall.php I can't delete plugin from plugins page (WP shows "Deletion failed: Are you sure you want to do this? Please try again." notification). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. One of security checks I used interfere with delete_option:

```
check_admin_referer
```